# Fetch Value from template tag in javascript in lightning web component

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-web-components, javascript-controller, lightning-inputfield

Please refer to below markup.

```
<lightning-record-edit-form key={field.key} object-api-name="Callback__c" layout-type="Full" >
   <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
       <template for:each={field.lstFields} for:item="fieldList" >
           <lightning-input-field if:true={isField} key={fieldList.key} field-name={fieldList.fieldName} class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2"> 
           </lightning-input-field>
        </template>
    </div>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

Is it possible to fetch a value of `{fieldList.fieldName}` in javascript function `isField()` of lightning web component?

I want to check if fieldname='x' in lightning-input-field tage.

Comment: What exactly is the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set something specific to each loop (iteration), you need to set the condition on loop variable (in each object).

HTML:

```
    <lightning-button label="Toggle Type" onclick={toggleType}></lightning-button>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Account">
        <template for:each={fields} for:item="fld">
            <lightning-input-field key={fld.name}
                                   field-name={fld.name}
                                   if:true={fld.render}>
            </lightning-input-field>
        </template>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
```

JS:

```
@track fields = [
    { name: 'Name', render: true },
    { name: 'Type', render: false },
    { name: 'Rating', render: true }
];

toggleType() {
    this.fields.find(fld => fld.name === 'Type').render = !this.fields.find(fld => fld.name === 'Type').render;
}
```

On click of `Toggle Type`, it will show or hide the field `Type`.

Comment: Thanks @salesforce-sas for your answer.
But I was looking for if condition with arithmetic operators like if:true="{isField=='xyz'}. 
though later on I got to know that in lightning web component you can't use arithmetic operators in if condition. 

You have to do that in javascript.